# Can we upload files to google docs via linux shell script or python

Tags: file-upload, google-docs

Is it possible to upload files to google docs via commandline or bash or via python. i have plent of stuff to upload but i have only access to command line and shh nothing else.

is there way to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely.  You'll need the [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/). Python should do a lovely job.  There is also a bunch of example code from Google [here](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html) with examples doing just this [here](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#UploadingDocs).

Comment: Basically i have flv videos which i want to upload . they have now allowed videos as well. so will that work in that case

Comment: It's unclear to me how one can log in without using email/password.  There's no way I'm going to put my real account credentials into a script.  I don't see any way to add google Docs via the API console either.  There are no examples of doing OAuth based auth to docs that I can find.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_and_uploading_documents_and_files

Answer (score 0):

For bash access, this is a useful FUSE driver for mounting Google Docs:

http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-fs/

Google provides a python client to the gdata APIs:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/

And there are some useful python scripts that provide bash-like commands to access Google Docs:

http://code.google.com/p/gdatacopier/

Comment: Tried gdatacopier. It doesn't appear to work for Google apps for your domain.

Comment: Also, FUSE driver would be awesome.  The guy said he isn't maintaining it anymore, so I'm wary of trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive

For Ubuntu use gdrive-linux-x64:

```
$ wget -O gdrive "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA&export=download"

$ chmod +x gdrive

$ echo "Hello World" > hello.txt

$ ./gdrive upload hello.txt
Authentication needed
Go to the following url in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=##########
Enter verification code: 4/Zg#############er234

Uploading hello.txt
Uploaded 1g#############qU2 at 6.0 B/s, total 12.0 B

$ ./gdrive info 1g#############qU2
Id: 1g#############qU2
Name: hello.txt
Path: hello.txt
Mime: text/plain
Size: 12.0 B
Created: 2018-09-25 13:47:24
Modified: 2018-09-25 13:47:24
Md5sum: e59ff97941044f85df5297e1c302d260
Shared: True
Parents: 0AL#############3VA
ViewUrl: https://drive.google.com/a/positrace.com/file/d/1g#############qU2/view?usp=drivesdk
DownloadUrl: https://drive.google.com/a/positrace.com/uc?id=1g#############qU2&export=download
```

Comment: Seems that Google didn't authorized this app to connect, as of today: tried with `gdrive-linux-x64` release, didn't work, unable to get the authorization code.